# $X^n-a$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}$ implies no zeros of $X^p-a$ in $\mathbb{F}$, $p|n, p<n$ a prime factor.

Tags: galois-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field of characteristic zero, and $\mathbb{F}[\alpha]$ its radical extension, i.e. $\alpha$ is a zero of $X^n-a \in \mathbb{F}[X],$ and $X^n-a$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}.$ Let $n=pq,$ where $p$ is a prime, and $q$ is a positive integer greater than $1$ (otherwise it would already be a prime radical extension. I'm trying to prove that every tower of radical extensions can be extended to a tower of **prime** radical extensions, where the degree of every extension is prime); therefore, $[\mathbb{F}[\alpha] : \mathbb{F}]=n.$

Then, $\alpha^q$ is a root of $X^p - a \in \mathbb{F}[X],$ so $\mathbb{F}[\alpha^q]$ is an extension of $\mathbb{F}.$ In order to show that it's also a **radical** extension, I'd need to prove that $X^p-a$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F},$ i.e. that it has no zeroes in $\mathbb{F}.$ How can I do this? I've tried assuming the opposite and trying to get a contradiction, with no success.

Comment: $x^3-8$ has a root in $\Bbb R$, but $x^{15}-8$ has none.

Comment: Yes, that's true, that's because $\mathbb{R} \leq \mathbb{C}$ is already a prime extension. My question was ill-posed. I've edited it accrodingly.

Comment: You need to list your assumptions more clearly. $x^4+4$ has no zeros in $\Bbb{Q}$, but it is not irreducible, because $x^4+4=(x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2)$. Actually I don't think that in the definition of a radical extension it is required that $x^n-a$ would have to be irreducible.

Comment: Yes, I've been noticing that the textbook I'm reading has different definitions than many standard textbooks. However, I'm too deep in and I feel too emotionally involved to just abandon it and start a different one (which I will definitely do once I finish this one, for the sake of clarity). Also, your counterexample isn't valid in my case, because $p$ is a prime. For a prime $p,$ $X^p-a$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}$ iff it has no zeros in $\mathbb{F}.$

Comment: Oh, I think I've just noticed what you meant. You meant the "where $X^n - a$ has no zeros in $\mathbb{F}$" part. $n$ doesn't have to be a prime, so "has no zeros" and "is irreducible" aren't equivalent! According to my textbook's definition, radical extensions require $X^n-a$ to be irreducible, not "without zeros" in $\mathbb{F}$. I've edited the question (again), thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I'm sorry about the mix-up, I've been reading a lot of field theory in a short amount of time and everything's a bit of a mixed bag right now.